# How to improve peewee's insert_many performance besides chunking?

Tags: performance, sqlite, insert, peewee

How to improve peewee's `insert_many` performance besides chunking? e.g.

```
from peewee import *
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(...)
data = df.to_dict('records')
for batch in chunked(data, chunk_size=100):
   SomeModel.insert_many(batch).execute()
```

Would increasing sqlite's `cursor.arraysize` help? any other performance setting?

Comment: Are you using transactions they can substantially increase performance. http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#managing-transactions

Comment: @MikeT indeed that's the case, I didn't think about it, you're right.

Comment: Transactions are recommended http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#bulk-inserts